# Airbrake: Why I'm seeing ActionController::RoutingErrors in my dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

We're seeing errors in our airbrake log that are supposed to be ignored.  We're running in Rails 3.2.16, airbrake version 4.1.0

According to docs, ActionController::RoutingError will be ignored, but it's showing up in our dashboard and sent to us by email.

We also added

```
config.ignore << "ActionController::RoutingError"
```

to our Airbrake config, but we're still getting the notifications.  Am I missing something simple?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Airbrake 4.1.0 is unsupported. Latest version of the library is v5.3.0 and I highly recommend upgrading because it's very well maintained. As for your question, according to the same docs `ActionController::RoutingError` should be ignored by default, so you don't need to ignore it manually. I suggest to try to upgrade to Airbrake v4.3.6 to see if it fixes the problem (if you cannot upgrade to v5 at the moment).

Comment: We upgraded to 4.3.6 and will try it out.  Thanks